# What's wrong with this Julia swap! macro?

Tags: macros, julia

I'm trying to write a simple `swap!` macro in Julia, to understand the macro system. Here's my code so far:

```
macro swap!(x, y)
    quote
        local tmp = $(esc(y))
        $x = $(esc(y))
        $y = tmp
    end
end

a = 1
b = 2

@swap!(a, b)

# prints: a: 1, b: 2
println("a: $a, b: $b")
```

This runs without error, but isn't actually changing the values. Julia doesn't seem to have a function that just expands macros without executing them (as far as I can see), so this is hard to debug.

The equivalent quote in a REPL seems to work as expected:

```
julia> a = 1
1

julia> a_sym = :a
:a

julia> a_sym
:a

julia> b = 2
2

julia> b_sym = :b
:b

julia> eval(quote
       tmp = $a_sym
       $a_sym = $b
       $b_sym = tmp
       end)
1

julia> a
2

julia> b
1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the `a, b = b, a` assignment isn't enough?

Comment: @juliom that certainly works, but my intention was to learn Julia macros.

Comment: Julia does have macroexpand. Calling it is a little tricky though. `macroexpand(:(@swap x, y))`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you probably want something like below but are getting messed up by [hygiene](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#hygiene).  The trick is to escape correctly.

```
macro swap(x,y)
   quote
      local tmp = $(esc(x))
      $(esc(x)) = $(esc(y))
      $(esc(y)) = tmp
    end
end
```

Here's what it looks like expanded

```
julia> macroexpand(quote @swap(x,y) end)
quote  # none, line 1:
    begin  # none, line 3:
        local #189#tmp = x # line 4:
        x = y # line 5:
        y = #189#tmp
    end
end
```

The effect

```
julia> x
1

julia> y
2

julia> @swap(x,y)

julia> x
2

julia> y
1
```

By contrast your macro escapes y in one assignment correctly, but not in the other 2 statements and so sets the values of introduced variables rather than the intended x and y.

```
julia> macroexpand(quote @swap!(x,y) end)
quote  # none, line 1:
    begin  # none, line 3:
        local #208#tmp = y # line 4:
        #209#x = y # line 5:
        #210#y = #208#tmp
    end 
end
```

Comment: I've edited the answer to remove the `return` statement from the macros.  It is both unnecessary and erroneous.  It wasn't returning from the macro, but rather, it was *splicing* a return statement into whatever context you used the macro in!  That means if you had used it in a function then that function would have returned immediately after `@swap`! The value of a begin block is simply the value of its last expression.

Answer (score 3):

According to this post https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Generic_swap , it seems Julia does't require any temporary variable.

```
a, b = b, a
```

So, we can write it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of Julia, but since its a cool sounding name, I popped in.  The tried and true pattern for swapping is:

```
swap(a, b)
    tmp <- a
    a <- b
    b <- tmp
```

Your code looks like this (unless I don't understand Julia, in which case I'll happily delete this answer)...

```
swap(a, b)
    tmp <- b
    a <- b
    b <- tmp
```

which records the value of b, then loses the value of a by writing b over it, then sets b to its original value stored in tmp.

Comment: Aha, well spotted! That's not quite enough to fix it, but it's definitely a problem with the code.

Answer (score -1):

While the accepted answer works just fine, I think the use of the temp variable is possibly missing out on some of the conceptual power of the macro.  I would write it like this...

```
macro swap!(x,y)
  quote
    $(esc(x)) = $(eval(y))
    $(esc(y)) = $(eval(x))
    return
  end
end
```

Then

```
julia> test1 = 1
1

julia> test2 = 2
2

julia> macroexpand(:(@swap! test1 test2))
quote  # none, line 3:
    test1 = 2 # line 4:
    test2 = 1 # line 5:
    return
end
```

Since the macro returns a string / expression which will be evaluated at run-time, you might as well just skip the temp variable and put the values you want directly into the returned string.

Comment: That only works in global scope. You generally don't want to use `eval`, and especially not in macros.

Comment: Interesting.  I only learned about macros this morning and your comment just made me address multiple misunderstandings.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also see [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706181/whats-wrong-with-this-julia-swap-macro#comment47110174_25706425) about the quoted return statement within macros.